# Woocommerce how to change the color of a checkout field text label

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming, woocommerce-checkout-fields

Good afternoon,

Maybe someone came across such a question. How to change the text of a defined field in a checkout. All fields refer to one label.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which one? The actual `text` of the label or its `color`?

For the actual text of the label use the following `filter` hook! For example if you want to change the `first name label` in the `billing section`:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'your_custom_checkout_fields', 20);

function your_custom_checkout_fields($fields){

    $fields['billing']['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'testing label 101!';

    # example of other fields
    # $fields['billing']['billing_last_name']['label'] = 'some label!'; 
    # $fields['billing']['billing_country']['label'] = 'some other label!';
    # $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['label'] = 'other label';
    # $fields['billing']['billing_email']['label'] = 'your label';
}
```

If you want to change its color, then use the following css rule:

```css
.woocommerce #billing_first_name_field label {

  color: pink; /* you could replace pink with any color you want!!! */

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I only used css and it helped me


.woocommerce #billing_eu_vat_field label {

  color: #9d2235;

}